# Android - Drag and Drop Fragments in screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop, android-gridview

I have to put different views with different sizes in one screen and should have Drag and Drop functionality between them.

I have found some libraries which does have this functionality. Can I use fragments in GridView which can be drag and drop at different places